Does Kafka Consumer Ingress or Egress traffic in port 9092
I got a rather silly question. I am using Terraform for creating some security group rules and EC2 instances.
One of them runs a Kafka broker in redpanda, and I expose for external sources port 9092. That has its own rules where I allow ingress in 9092 and all egress tcp traffic.
I am wondering for producers an consumers what the rule should be. If I need to get specific, do I allow only egress on 9092 tcp? Do I need both ingress and egress for that port?
In essence, a producer I assume begins the communication, but does consumers receive, thus need to expose port 9092?

The brokers are not sending traffic at the clients, so therefore it would only be egress from the client machine to the brokers
If you want to use Kafka Streams interactive queries, or ksqlDB, or Schema Registry, then you'll need to expose additional ingress ports.
